# Action of Möbius Group

Tags: complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

By a circle in $\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$, we mean a circle in plane $\mathbb{C}$ or a straight in $\mathbb{C}$ union with $\infty$.

Given two circles in $\mathbb{C}\cup \{ \infty\}$, does there exists a Möbius transformation $z\mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ which takes these two circles to concentric circles?

(We can ask the same question by considering finitely many circles.)

Comment: You should require the two circles to be disjoint, otherwise the answer is trivially no.

Comment: Yes! Two intersecting circle will intersect after Mobius transformation also! Thanks for pointing out it.